# Skip error lines while loading data to mysql table from delimited file

Tags: mysql

I am loading data from text file to mysql table using following query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "myFile.csv"
INTO TABLE some_table
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (admin,consumer);
```

But when my file contains some error lines it is not able skip that line and the whole process stops at that place. I mean if my file format like :

```
----------
sankr : kumar
----------
ramesh:rao
----------
new users add here
----------
sri : vennla
----------
anu : bhavya
----------
```

I have to load by skipping the line "new users add here". How can do this?

Answer (score 9):

The keyword you're looking for is `IGNORE`.

As in:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "myFile.csv" IGNORE
INTO TABLE some_table
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (admin,consumer);
```

Comment: Are you sure? From the mysql documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html `IGNORE` means ignore lines that have duplicate primary key with existed row.

Comment: Hm. I do see that, but it worked for me. I can't remember where I got that from. I can test later to see if it ignores all errors or just duplicate key errors.

Comment: @StefanoGiacone Did you try it?  It works for me and a second look at the documentation describes IGNORE as causing warnings instead of errors and continuing to import the file.

Comment: My confirmation, at least it worked, when I have data with wrong length.

Answer (score 1):

I found that
`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename' REPLACE`
would quit after a data format error (illegal date),
but
`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename'` 
and
`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename' IGNORE`
continued.

This is contrary to the MySql documentation (ver 5.0) as far as I can tell.

Answer (score -3):

It's not possible to skip lines inside the data using `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Just delete the record later using a separate query.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE column = "new users add here";
```

Comment: My file contains error line so my query will generate an error while loading and it won't load anything to database. Its stops execution. Any alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: "ERROR 1261(01000): Row 73 doesnot contain data for all columns."  It is not loading even single line to database.

Comment: @sankar ah, I see. Didn't know LOAD DATA did that. In that case, unless you find an option to ignore incomplete data in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), you may have to change your incoming data.

Comment: we doing bulk import, and on top you suggesting to execute delete queries. double work. downvoted

Comment: @Parag so suggest a better way?