# Skip invalid data when importing .tsv using MySQL LOAD DATA IFILE

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, csv

I am trying to import a bunch of .tsv files into a MySQL database. However, in some of the files, there are errors in some of the rows (these files were generated from another system where data is manually inputted, so these errors are human errors). When I try to use LOAD DATA INFILE to import them, when the command gets to that row of bad data, the command writes NULL values for that field and then proceeds to stop the command, whereas I need it to keep going.

The bad rows look like this:

```
value1, value 2, value 3
bob, 3, st
john, 4, rd
dianne4ln
jack, 7, cir
```

I've made sure the line terminators are correct, and use Ignore and Replace parameters to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IGNORE` in your query to skip error lines and proceed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523956/skip-error-lines-while-loading-data-to-mysql-table-from-delimited-file) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: As I said in the end of my  question, I've used IGNORE but it doesn't help. Also my load data doesn't actually throw any errors, just some unrelated warnings, it just stops the  function at the bad row.