# My Sql Bulk inserts loading the data with truncating

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy, truncation

I am trying to load the data from CSV file to MYSql database through bulk insert option. Here are the below create table syntax and CSV file

```
CREATE TABLE discounts (
    id INT NOT NULL ,
    title VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    expired_date DATE NOT NULL,
    amount VARCHAR(255 ) NOT NULL

);
```

**CSV file format:**

```
"475","Back","20140401","FFFF"
"476","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","20140901","DDD"
```

**SQL Query :**

```
LOAD DATA  INFILE 'C:\Users\karthick\Desktop\data.csv' 
INTO TABLE discounts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

In above create table syntax i have specified the column "title" data length to "10". But the value in data file for second row exceeds the length 10.

When i executed the SQL query the data are loaded successfully to MySQL database and here are the below output & My values in second row is getting truncated for the field "title". Could you please suggest how to stop loading the row without truncating it. Also it should load the next consecutive row without terminating if the data are appropriate. Please suggest

**Database Output :**

```
'475', 'Back', '2014-04-01', 'FFFF'
'476', 'bbbbbbbbbb', '2014-09-01', 'DDD'
```

Comment: Use `title VARCHAR(100)`?  I mean, if the field has a fixed width of 10, then it can only store 10 characters, right?

Comment: I am expecting that DB should throw an error in case of data length exceeds the limit. Is there any possibilities ? please suggest

Comment: Do you know the maximum width of this data?  If so, then just create the appropriate table and load the data.

Comment: I know the width of the data, But in some case it may violate. So is there any possibility to reject the complete row on the database side ? My objective  is the row should be rejected.

Comment: I gave you an answer below, just one option.  There are probably other ways of doing it.

Comment: Thanks! I have replied to it. Let's wait for other experts on the subject

Comment: I think only the the INSERT statement has this by default(it throws error if column does not fit), you could add a modifier called IGNORE which fails this row silently. But thats not BULK anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Here is trick you may use.  Assuming the maximum width `title` you want to persist is 100 characters, you may create the table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE discounts (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(101) NOT NULL,    -- slightly larger than desired max width
    expired_date DATE NOT NULL,
    amount VARCHAR(255 ) NOT NULL
);
```

Then load your data as you were doing.  Records having titles which *exceed* a width of 100 would in fact have a width of 101 in your database table.  Then, you may target such records for deletion:

```
DELETE
FROM discounts
WHERE LENGTH(title) > 100;
```

If you want, you can also now resize the `title` column to a width of exactly 100:

```
ALTER TABLE discounts MODIFY COLUMN title VARCHAR(100);
```

There *might* be a way to do this from `LOAD DATA`, but in general this tool is fairly simple and designed to just blindly load data into a MySQL table.  `LOAD DATA` does have the ability to transform data as it is read, but I am not sure if it can block it.

Comment: This is time consuming process, Let's say if i have 1 million records with 200 columns. For example if i have vulnerable in 10 columns, the above suggested answer will take much time. I am looking for an option like in oracle, In the same case oracle will reject the complete record and the same will be logged into "*.bad.CSV" file. I am looking for similar option in MySql also.

Comment: Then I don't have an answer for you, sorry.  But, I'll leave this up unless someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Yes Tim, We will wait for other active specialist also. Many thanks for your info

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, below are few points that you want to achieve:
1) Data should not get truncated if title length is more than specified field length as per table structure.
2) If title length is more, then that record should get skipped while doing an importing of records & rest of the process should continue ahead.

Answer as per mysql database taken into consideration:

You can make use of sql_mode as TRADITIONAL (Make MySQL behave like a “traditional” SQL database system. A simple description of this mode is “give an error instead of a warning” when inserting an incorrect value into a column. Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html)

Now after setting this mode, while doing records import, error will occur if any incorrect data or value out of range is getting to insert into table.

Next part, for out of range values their is no way to skip the error rows. You can check existing discussion link: [Skip error lines while loading data to mysql table from delimited file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523956/skip-error-lines-while-loading-data-to-mysql-table-from-delimited-file)

For skipping rows which are breaking unique constraints or possibly creating duplicate records, can be skipped using IGNORE keyword along with LOAD DATA INFILE.

Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html